# Unable to get appropriate JSON response for a jQuery autocomplete script

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I've just about completed a jQuery script to GET a JSON response from my webservice in asp.net.

The form will now communicate with the webservice and will attempt to get the appropriate data for my autocomplete textbox but I cannot seem to format the data appropriately, as to get an array for the suggestion area.

When I type text into the box, I get brackets like [], rather than client names like I should be.

**Here is my aspx page...**

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
type = "text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
type = "text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=ClientSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/GetClients.asmx/GetClientNames") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }

                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#<%=hfClientID.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });

    });
</script> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Gadget" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" Runat="Server">
    <h1>jQuery Autocomplete Lab</h1>
    <asp:TextBox ID="ClientSearch" CssClass="autocomplete" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientID" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick = "Submit" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Here is my webservice**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service_CS
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class GetClients : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public GetClients()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetClientNames(string prefix)
    {
        List<string> clients = new List<string>();
        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name], [ID] FROM [Current] WHERE " + "[Name] LIKE @SearchText";
                prefix = "'" + prefix + "%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        clients.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]));
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            string json = js.Serialize(clients);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: When you run this in debug mode, can you confirm that the `GetClientNames` function is being hit by the ajax call and that it is generating and returning the data that you are looking for? If yes, then if you set a javascript breakpoint in dev tools inside the ajax function, what data do you see coming back?

Comment: Its being hit. 
I'm using the developer toolbar in Firefox to confirm. My webform performs a GET method and the webservice responds with a POST method.
I'm not sure about the JavaScript breakpoint though. I'll have to try it in VS

Comment: "webservice responds with a POST method" - this doesn't make sense. I think you are trying to say that the page loads with a GET request, and the ajax method then makes a POST request to the webservice, right? If you are using the dev toolbar then that is the place to set the JS breakpoint. VS only handles server-side breakpoints.

Comment: My oligopolies,
Well, I've got a few messages in the log here.

01:18:42.476 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js:6
01:18:42.898 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. browserLink:37
01:18:43.204 no element found send:1
01:18:43.386 no element found send:1
01:18:43.448 no element found send:1
01:18:46.366 Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. jquery.min.js:54
01:18:46.366 Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. jquery.min.js:55

That seems like a jquery issue.

Comment: This may be what we're looking for.

First time I've used FireBug

 
 
C
 "d-CD9AA129-CA,0|Cb,4|Cc,0"
 
M
 []

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense, I'll keep looking.

Comment: JavaScript Response

{"d":"[]"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your client is getting back no data (implied by the empty brackets that you see in the response), this implies that there is an issue with your server-side webmethod.

Try running through the webmethod in debug mode, and make sure that the data retrieval is running as it should, and that the json-serialized string is created properly.

Comment: Okay, I'll will try this.
I appreciate your response. I will keep the post open for now until I get the results, should anyone else have other suggestions as well.